# when V>0, what happens in ideal diode?

Tags: diodes

[image]

All diodes are ideal and the answer V is +3V in problem (e).
So my question is why we can't let all diodes to be forward-biased. What happens when V is +1V?
Is it because the current flows to infinity in ideal diode? Or is there any reason?
And what happens to ideal diode when Voltage is larger than 0?

Comment: It conducts.  Current is limited by resistor.

Comment: An ideal diode would still block when reverse biased. Otherwise it's not an ideal diode, it's an ideal piece of wire. The top diode conducts and drops 0V. The second diode is reverse-biased by 1V. The third diode is reverse-biased by 2V.

Answer (score 4):

In this highly simplified diode model, the diode acts as either an open circuit (when reverse biased) or a short circuit (when forward biased).

In your example, if all diodes were forward biased, then the output voltage would have to be 1 V, 2 V, and 3 V at the same time. This is a logical contradiction.

But it’s easy to resolve, because if the output is 3 V, then the 2nd and 3rd diodes are reverse biased, and the contradiction is eliminated.

Comment: You beat my comment by 20 seconds...

Comment: @AdamLawrence it could still be worthwhile, even to post as an answer, in case your wording resonates better with OP or some future reader.

Comment: I'll see if OP re-engages; if so I will.

Comment: Thank you everyone :)